# Unable to create Google Meet Link in python with django

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to create a Google Meet event using the Google Calendar API in Python, but I'm encountering an HttpError. Here's the code I'm using to create the event:

```
import logging
import uuid

from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials as GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

from courses.models import Teacher


logger = logging.getLogger('google_calendar')

def create_google_meet_event(teacher: Teacher, start_time, end_time, summary, description):
    # Retrieve the service account file path
    service_account_file_path = teacher.service_account_file.path

    # Use service account credentials
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_file_path, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'])
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

    event = {
        'summary': summary,
        'description': description,
        'start': {
            'dateTime': start_time.isoformat(),
            'timeZone': 'UTC',
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': end_time.isoformat(),
            'timeZone': 'UTC',
        },
        'conferenceData': {
            'createRequest': {
                'requestId': uuid.uuid4().hex,
                'conferenceSolutionKey': {
                    'type': 'hangoutsMeet'
                },
            }
        }
    }

    try:
        # Insert the event into the teacher's calendar
        created_event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', conferenceDataVersion=1, body=event).execute()
        # Get the Google Meet link
        meet_link = created_event.get('hangoutLink')
        return meet_link

    except HttpError as error:
        # Handle the error as appropriate in your Django view
        logger.error(error)
        raise Exception(error)
```

I have ensured that the service_account_file_path is correct, and the teacher object contains the correct credentials.

```
Exception: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?conferenceDataVersion=1&alt=json returned "Invalid conference type value.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Invalid conference type value.'}]">
```

Ive already gone through most of the solutions on StackOverflow but none of them seemed to work.